# How to raise standard error from a rspec test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

So I have an rspec test that I am trying to get my program to validate against:

code snippet from rspec test:

```
context '#validate(test_tool)' do
   it { expect(test_tool.validate).to raise_error StandardError }
```

code snippet from test_tool (test_tool is the program I wrote to pass the rspec test) Inside test_tool there are multiple methods, but I just pulled out the one method that the rspec test is looking for:

```
def self.validate
     raise StandardError
end
```

I have googled everywhere. No matter how I attempt to raise this error. I keep getting an error. Please see snippet of console output:

```
example at ./spec/training_site/spec_test.rb:56 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) MyClass #validate(test_tool) 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(MyClass.validate).to raise_error StandardError }
     StandardError:
       StandardError
```

Line 56 is just the 2nd line from the 1st code snippet.

Basically, I'm looking for troubleshooting and or example on how I should accomplish this.

Comment: Can you try expect{MyClass.validate} instead of expect(MyClass.validate) ?

Comment: @Maxim - yeah that appeared to work. Why did I need to use curly braces instead of parenthesis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is correct spec. You should use {} (block brackets) since you are waiting for it to raise error. Simple brackets that you have use are for values checking.

```
context '#validate(test_tool)' do
  it { expect{test_tool.validate}.to raise_error StandardError }
```